# Assistance with VBScript to backup log files

Tags: backup, vbscript

I am attempting to write a VBScript to backup the log files from a handful of network computers to a shared drive on a network server.

This is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Const OverWriteFiles = True

Dim fso, objShell
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim WshNetwork
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim Computername, regComputerName, nfolder, folderdate, fday, fmonth, fyear
Dim path1, path2, fdate, objFolder

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

regComputerName = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control" &_
    "\ComputerName\ComputerName\ComputerName"
ComputerName = objShell.RegRead(regComputerName)

fdate = Date()
fday = (Day(fdate))
If Len(fday) < 2 Then
  fday = 0 & fday
End If
fmonth = (Month(fdate))
If Len(fmonth) < 2 Then
  fmonth = 0 & fmonth
End If
fyear = (Year(fdate))
folderdate = "." & fyear & "_" & fmonth & "_" & fday
nfolder = Computername & folderdate
path1 = "C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\"
path2 = "Z:\test\"

If objFSO.FolderExists (path2 & nfolder) Then
    objFSO.deleteFolder (path2 & nfolder)
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder (path2 & nfolder)
Else
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(path2 & nfolder)
End if
path2 = path2 & nfolder
fso.CopyFolder path1, path2, OverWriteFiles
```

When debugging the script, I keep getting an error on the final line that says "Microsoft VBScript runtime error (42, 1) : Path not found"

Not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are both paths:
`path1 = "C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\" and path2 = "Z:\test\"`accessible to the user the script is running as? I assume the issue is with `Z:\test`.  Can you confirm that by changing that to a local path that you know exists the script works?  When you map a drive, when UAC is enabled it's not mapped for both tokens by default, Google for `EnableLinkedConnections` maybe it's related as you don't mention the context the script is running is relative to the account the drive was mapped for.

Comment: Yes, both paths are accessible to the user the script is running as. I can access the Z:\test drive both through Windows Explorer and at the command line. Interesting point, the script is creating the folder in path2 but it's not copying anything to the folder.

Comment: Your Dim's & Set's have inconsistencies, your regComputerName = and ComputerName = both appear to depend upon each other and neither can run before the other, and I don't see where you are setting the path1 to anywhere other than on your computer's own C: drive.

Comment: @Brian the regComputerName and ComputerName part seem to be working correctly as the program creates a folder in path2 that is exactly as desired. The only problem is that the files are not copying from path1 to the newly created folder. The way I read the CopyFolder command documentation, I just need to declare the path to the data I want copied (path1) and the path to the location I want the information copied to (path2) and whether I want the information overwritten or not (OverWriteFiles).

Comment: Even though the program is creating the destination folder, I get the error that the path is not found. Could this be referring to path1 and not path2. Path1 seems to be correctly identified as the log folder on drive C:.

Comment: I have added wscript.echo commands for both path1 and path2 just above the CopyFolder command. Both echos show the paths as being as they should be, but the copy command still returns a Path not found error.

Comment: Try your path as ```path1 = "C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\*.*"``` (with wildcards) or ```path1 = "C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs"``` (no slash on end)

Comment: @Brian I have tried it with both of those options and it still doesn't work. I think it could be a permissions issue with path1. I can access that folder through Windows Explorer normally, but in order to access it from the command line, I have to run cmd as administrator. Is there a way to pass permissions in vbs?

Comment: take off your overwrite parameter and check again

Comment: That doesn't work either. I originally had the script without overwrite but added it when the script wouldn't run. Just to be sure, I just took it off and tried it again but no luck.

Comment: I'm almost positive now that it is a permissions thing. I took out the copy folder structure and replaced it with objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\*.*", path2 and now I get "permission denied" instead of "path not found".